# How can I trigger an event when multiple items added at once to Outlook Folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

I use event handlers in VBA and Outlook frequently. One of them is one which marks any item which is deleted to be marked as read.

```
Private Sub deletedItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Application_Startup
    On Error Resume Next
    Item.UnRead = False

End Sub
```

Declared via:

```
Private WithEvents deletedItems As Outlook.Items
```

and initialized in `Application_Startup` as:

```
Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNameSpace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set deletedItems = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items
```

Unfortunately, this does not affect all the items if I delete multiple items at once.

Is there a way I can do something to hijack this process somehow? I looked into using the [_beforeDelete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa209979%28v=office.11%29.aspx) event but you have to set the item correctly each time, which if I could do this problem wouldn't exist anyways.

---

Apparently I wasn't clear - the use case I have is when I delete messages via the delete key from my inbox, drafts, whatever.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Set deletedItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).Items`? ..or `olNameSpace` is a variable of yours, assigned elsewhere?

Comment: @retailcoder yes, I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to.

I was curious about your question so I opened up Outlook and wrote this code in `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Private WithEvents items As Outlook.items

Public Sub SetItems()
    Set items = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                           .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems) _
                           .items
End Sub

Private Sub items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim mail As MailItem

    On Error Resume Next
        Set mail = Item
        Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not mail Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox mail.Subject
        mail.UnRead = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I ran `SetItems` from the immediate pane, went to my inbox and deleted a SMS message - as expected `mail` was `Nothing`. Then I deleted a single email, and got the message with the mail's subject.

When I selected two emails and hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>, the event was fired once for each selected email, so I saw two message boxes - it just works! :)

The Outlook API doesn't seem to offer an event which would handle all deletions at once.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction. My code is nearly identical, but I had been calling something too which after I traced it through was actually re-initializing my event handler - which then doesn't process the additional events.

Comment: Unrelated, but I find it funny that we have identical rep scores..(until you accept my answer :) Glad I could help, and thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @ElysianFields your comment saved my sanity! I had code that was firing in the `Application_ItemLoad` event that reinitialized my equivalent of your `deletedItems` object, which happened just before the ItemAdd event would have triggered the event procedure.

Answer (score 0):

i have (almost) exactly the same code and it works also for multiple items - only after sleep-mode Outlook seems to forget how to handle deleted items...

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents itDeleted As items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set itDeleted = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDeletedItems).items
End Sub

Private Sub itDeleted_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
'MsgBox "deleted-sub fired" 'this only for test-purposes
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
  Item.UnRead = False
End If
End Sub
```

I think the difference in the definition of "deletedItems" is the problem; that you are not checking the mailitem-property is also not optimal.

Hope this helps,
Max